# Automatically scheduling SQL query results to be exported to a csv file

Tags: sql, export-to-csv, job-scheduling

I have tried to read up on this topic and I am still a bit unclear how to proceed. This seemed like a fairly basic task but it has been nowhere as simple as I had assumed. I have several SQL queries written and I want to be able to schedule them to run on a certain day each month and then automatically be exported to a .csv file in a selected folder. This will then allow them to be automatically uploaded into a BI and reporting tool that our firm uses (this part I know how to take care of).

I am fairly well versed in the writing of SQL queries, but everything beyond that I am pretty lost on. Right now I am using Microsoft SQL Management Studio 17. I thought that maybe scheduling jobs using the SQL Server Agent would be the solution, but the more I read about that and go down that path, the less I am convinced that it will allow me to export the query results into the .csv file that I need for it to be picked up. It is also important that these results are exported without headers.

Does anyone have any solutions for this? I am happy to answer any follow up questions if I am at all unclear.

Comment: SSIS is designed to do this.  I would highly recommend it over other pure SQL approaches.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/load-data-to-from-excel-with-ssis?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a job within the SQL server management studio to handle the whole thing.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/7d2280cf-3b33-46f7-ba82-4131e8a841c0